# why is it not possible to print from the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

```
class x{
     int register = 10;
     public x(){ //default constructor 

        System.out.print(register*10);//print

     }//child class end
```

well i thought it would print but perhaps it doesnt. Whys that?

Comment: Can you use that way of printing outside of the constructuor? What makes you think that you cannot use it inside?

Comment: Do you actually call the constructor? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Guys, i just realized im supposd to call the constructor. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, without seeing how you call your x.java it would be hard to help:

*Main.java*

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        X myX = new X();
    }
}
```

*X.java*

```
public class X {

    public X(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

In order for the constructor to activate you have to remember to call it from the main thread.

Comment: oh wow. im dumb. Thank u so much

Comment: i forgot i have to CALL the constructor in order to run it. smh